# UICustom cell of UItableview not fitting the tableview width

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

[image]

My `UICustomCell` of `UITableView` is not fitting up the tableview width for iPhone 6 and 6 +
I have take nib for it.
one for iPhone and one for iPad

Comment: Show some code what you've done.

Comment: there is nothing i have set from code all the thing done from xib itself, i have used UIautoresizingmask .

Comment: @adijazz91 please add your code as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 2):

```
screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;

UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{        
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Prototype Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath]; 
   cell.frame.size.width = tableView.frame.size.width;
}
```

Comment: i have done it , its not working either. the cell returns the frame (0,0,320,209) alway in case of iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

this is my activity inspector of my custom cell.xib 
please have a look at the image
[image: it always return (0,0,320,290) and autoresizining is enabled in this xib]